# Add layer to GeoServer workspace which is not default

Tags: geoserver, layers, web-service, workspace

Adding a layer to GeoServer in the default workspace, I do it this way:

1. Layers> "Add a new layer"
2. In the "Add layers from" menu, select the source
3. Click the "Configure new SQL view" link
4. Type view name and SQL statement
5. If the query is correct, the layer attributes will be displayed
6. Check the Identifier checkbox next to the Id line
7. In the geometry line, select the geometry type (eg polygon)
8. Enter 3765 in the SRID column
9. Save
10. The editing form opens
11. In the "Bounding Boxes" section, click the "Compute from SRS bounds" and "Compute from native bounds" links
    12.save

How can I add a layer to workspace that is not default?

There is some checkbox or I need to change my default workspace?

Comment: create a new workspace, add your data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to configure the workspace on a per-layer basis, it will end up in the same workspace of the store it comes from.

So, to change the workspace of a layer, you'll have to change the workspace of its store. That will also move all other layers coming from the same store, mind.

Comment: Thank you for answer, the solution was to create new store